# "after all" hook error while running test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

This is my test body:

```js
/// <reference types = "cypress" />

it('Testing story book button primary', function(){
    cy.visit('https://storybook.prod.ublox-website.ch4.amazee.io/iframe.html?id=components-button--primary&viewMode=story')
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.eyesOpen({
        appName: 'Story book',
        testName: 'check button primary',
    });
    cy.eyesCheckWindow();
    cy.eyesClose();
});
```

I have attached a screenshot of my error at the end it displays this error( I have attached).[image]

Can someone please let me know why I am getting this error? I am stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult for someone to help debug this with the limited code provided I think. Mainly because I'm not sure what your `after()` block looks like, the error that is being throw isn't occurring in this test, it's occurring in the teardown code when `body.success` doesn't exist (what results in `body.success` existing?). Additionally `eyesOpen` and `eyesCheckWindow` and `eyesClose` seem to be custom commands specific to Applitools, I'd at least recommend adding that as a tag or edit your post to include that information because that isn't part of the general testers' Cypress workflow/plugin stack.

Other than that, I'd try adding `cy.log(body.error)` or `console.log(body.error)` or adding the `after()` block, and add the results to your question.

Answer (score 0):

On a separate note, you can try using the Applitools example test structure

```
  it('works', () => {
    cy.visit('https://applitools.com/helloworld');
    cy.eyesOpen({
      appName: 'Hello World!',
      testName: 'My first JavaScript test!',
      browser: { width: 800, height: 600 },
    });
    cy.eyesCheckWindow('Main Page');
    cy.get('button').click();
    cy.eyesCheckWindow('Click!');
    cy.eyesClose();
  });
});
```

or their "best practice" example structure

```
describe('Hello world', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.eyesOpen({
      appName: 'Hello World!',
      browser: { width: 800, height: 600 },
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.eyesClose();
  });

  it('My first JavaScript test!', () => {
    cy.visit('https://applitools.com/helloworld');
    cy.eyesCheckWindow('Main Page');
    cy.get('button').click();
    cy.eyesCheckWindow('Click!');
  });
});
```

Both look like they're passing text into eyesCheckWindow but I also am not familiar with applitools so this could be useless information.